# Get attr from each parent and set for each child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have datepicker from jquery-ui and I need to set id for each day (a with class .ui-state-default) in format: year-month-day.

This is my solution, that I want to make working for every day. For now I get this:

> id="2015-2-1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303112345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031"

```
var year = $(".ui-state-default").parent('td').data('year');
var month = $(".ui-state-default").parent('td').data('month');
var day = $(".ui-state-default").parent('td').children().text();
        $(".ui-state-default").attr("id", "" + year + '-' + month + '-' + day + "");
```

And this is sample part of datepicker code.

```
<tr>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2015">
                        <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2015">
                        <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2015">
                        <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2015">
                        <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2015">
                        <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2015">
                        <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="2" data-year="2015">
                        <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: culd you describe more precisely your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest iterating over the .ui-state-default elements via jquery each then performing that same code within it.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
$('.ui-state-default').each(function() {
    var parentData = $(this).parent().data();
    $(this).attr("id", "" + parentData.year + '-' + parentData.month + '-' + this.text + "");
});
```

Comment: For your solution I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error in 2-nd line. Any suggestions? I have already tried with .each() but mayby I'm too tired to make it right :(